# Bootstrap data-toggle="button" unexpected focus

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why is the `.focus` class being added to the style of the button? This is preventing the appearance of the button to change. I got the code from the Bootstrap site. There, only the `.active` class is toggled, not `focus`.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            Single toggle
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I was working on a checkbox, but then I got this data-toggle="button" which does the same thing, switch the css to active. But it adds focus incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please include the CSS in your question?

Answer (score 1):

With your given code I was not able to see any focus with the button there. Once I added the class focus, it gave the result. To resolve this type of issues I always use chrome inspection tools. ctr + shift + i will show if the loaded html file still has the focus class there in it. 
You can see the example below.
[image]

if that is not an issue here, you are misunderstanding the focus class. See the example here.
https://codepen.io/rj99/pen/QQBoma

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            Single toggle
</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary focus" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
            Single toggle
</button>
```

Comment: I think the focus class is being added only in Chrome. I executed your link both in Chrome and Safari and the focus css is added on Chrome (when clicking/toggling the button).

Answer (score 1):

The class `.focus` goes along with the pseudo-class `:focus` in Bootstrap 4.

Here an example:

```
.btn:focus, .btn.focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}
```

As to WHY it's done that way?

The reason will be: **Ensuring cross-browser consistency**.

Form elements and buttons are notoriously difficult to style because many browsers often disregard attempts to style those elements (or try to meddle with their own ideas). So, those browsers that ignore styling rules of `:focus` are more likely to honor the styling rules of `.focus` because that's a "real" class, not a pseudo-class.

Something along those lines will be the reason.

> this is preventing the appearance of the button to change

That by itself should not prevent you from changing the appearance of the button. The focus class/pseudo-class only deals with the outline (actually box-shadow acting as the outline). Nothing else.